# hibernate how to count rows when there is order bys already present

Tags: hibernate

I just begin to learn hibernate, I googled and found nothing helpful.
I am using hibernate with h2 database, here is my code:

```
protected Object doRead(GridReadRequest rreq) {
        Session session = ALSA.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria("com.bgzchina.alsa.data.infra.Role");
        if(rreq.getSort() != null){
            for(SortDescriptor sd : rreq.getSort()){
                if(sd.getDir().equals("asc")){
                    criteria.addOrder(Order.asc(sd.getField()));
                }else{
                    criteria.addOrder(Order.desc(sd.getField()));
                }
            }
        }

        Filter filter;
        if((filter = rreq.getFilter()) != null){
            if(filter.getLogic().equals("and")){
                if(filter.getFilters() != null){
                    Conjunction c = null;
                    for(FilterDescriptor fd : filter.getFilters()){
                        if(fd.getOperator().equals("eq")){
                            c = Restrictions.and(Restrictions.eq(fd.getField(), fd.getValue()));
                        }else if(fd.getOperator().equals("neq")){
                            c = Restrictions.and(Restrictions.ne(fd.getField(), fd.getValue()));
                        }else if(fd.getOperator().equals("startswith")){
                            c = Restrictions.and(Restrictions.like(fd.getField(), fd.getValue(), MatchMode.START));
                        }else if(fd.getOperator().equals("contains")){
                            c = Restrictions.and(Restrictions.like(fd.getField(), fd.getValue(), MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
                        }else if(fd.getOperator().equals("endswith")){
                            c = Restrictions.and(Restrictions.like(fd.getField(), fd.getValue(), MatchMode.END));
                        }
                    }
                    criteria.add(c);
                }
            }else if(filter.getLogic().equals("or")){
                if(filter.getFilters() != null){
                    Disjunction c = null;
                    for(FilterDescriptor fd : filter.getFilters()){
                        if(fd.getOperator().equals("eq")){
                            c = Restrictions.or(Restrictions.eq(fd.getField(), fd.getValue()));
                        }else if(fd.getOperator().equals("neq")){
                            c = Restrictions.or(Restrictions.ne(fd.getField(), fd.getValue()));
                        }else if(fd.getOperator().equals("startswith")){
                            c = Restrictions.or(Restrictions.like(fd.getField(), fd.getValue(), MatchMode.START));
                        }else if(fd.getOperator().equals("contains")){
                            c = Restrictions.or(Restrictions.like(fd.getField(), fd.getValue(), MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
                        }else if(fd.getOperator().equals("endswith")){
                            c = Restrictions.or(Restrictions.like(fd.getField(), fd.getValue(), MatchMode.END));
                        }
                    }
                    criteria.add(c);
                }
            }

        }

        criteria.setFirstResult(rreq.getSkip());
        criteria.setMaxResults(rreq.getTake()); 
        List<Object> list = criteria.list();

        Long total = (Long)criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount()).uniqueResult();

        CRUDResponse response = new CRUDResponse();
        response.setData(list);
        response.setTotal(total.longValue());

        return response;
    }
```

if `rreq.getSort() != null`, I got a exception on this line:

```
Long total = (Long)criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount()).uniqueResult();
```

sql generated by hibernate while running against h2 database:

```
select count(*) as y0_ from ROLE_INFO this_ order by this_.roleID asc limit ?
```

exception:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "THIS_.ROLEID" must be in the GROUP BY list; SQL statement:
```

Maybe I can use two Criteria instances, one for query data, one for counting rows?
I am asking here for the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok from another SO question about this topic, I found a way to remove orders in Criteria

```
CriteriaImpl ci = (CriteriaImpl)criteria;
        Iterator<?> it = ci.iterateOrderings();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            it.next();
            it.remove();
        }
```

maybe it's not good, but I choose to take this as my solution. It works for me.